# Display a remote page using async javascript similar to how adsense does

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

First off I'm don't often code in js so I will attempt to describe what I would like to achieve, and hope someone understands my randomness enough to come up with an answer :)

I would like to add an async call like:

```
<script async src="//mydomain.com/loadpage.js"></script>
```

to a div in a page, and it would then load the remote page into that div. Similar to Adsense ad displays, or YouTube (yes I know thats a frame, but you get the idea).

I'm planning to build something out in PHP, and want to provide users an easy way to embed the data generated in a web page.

Would also be useful if it could live update/poll the page for changes on an interval, as the page will update every 3 minutes or so.

I have no-idea what to search for online to achieve this, so I'm hoping someone can give me some points, or code help. Thanks :)

Comment: Is javascript a condition? How about `iframe` linked to webpage with `meta tag refesh` set on 180s - wouldn't it do any good?

Comment: I'm trying to avoid that option, to make it easy for someone to implement on there website. But thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate you div content with a PHP service (that writes a smarty template, for example) and in the included js you write something like

```
$.ajax(
   url: 'your php service',
   success: function(html) {
       $("#divId").html(html);
   }
)
```

p.s.: you need jquery to be loaded

hope it could help